# python изменение глобальной переменной статическим методом класса

Tags: python, многопоточность, global-variables

Есть класс для запуска задачи по расписанию. Запускаю его отдельным процессом. Пытаюсь отследить изменение глобальной переменной, но она не меняется. Сообщения, выдаваемые классом меняются, а в `glob_check()` - всегда первоначальное значение. Как в `glob_check` получить `LAST_CHECK` измененное в `def check_news()` ????

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime
from multiprocessing.context import Process
LAST_CHECK = 'class'

class P_schedule:  # Class для работы с schedule

global LAST_CHECK

@staticmethod
def start_schedule():  # Запуск schedule
    global LAST_CHECK
    ######Параметры для schedule######
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(P_schedule.check_news)
    ##################################

    while True:  # Запуск цикла
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

@staticmethod
def check_news():
    global LAST_CHECK
    print("previos LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK)
    time.sleep(2)
    LAST_CHECK = 'Последняя проверка по расписанию ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("check_news by schedule LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK)
    # return LAST_CHECK

def glob_check():
    print("info LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK)

def start_process():#Запуск Process
    p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=()).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_process()
    while True:
        a = input("input 1 for exit")
        if a == "1":
            break
        glob_check()
```

Пытаюсь использовать `multiprocessing.Manager`,

```
import schedule

import time
import datetime
from ctypes import c_char_p
from multiprocessing.context import Process
from multiprocessing import Value, Manager

class P_schedule:  # Class для работы с schedule
    @staticmethod
    def start_schedule(LAST_CHECK):  # Запуск schedule
        print("schedule start")
        ######Параметры для schedule######
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(P_schedule.check_news(LAST_CHECK))
        ##################################

    while True:  # Запуск цикла
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

@staticmethod
def check_news(LAST_CHECK):
    print("previos LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK.value)
    time.sleep(2)
    LAST_CHECK.value = 'Последняя проверка по расписанию ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("check_news by schedule LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK.value)


def glob_check(LAST_CHECK):
    print("info LAST_CHECK = " + str(LAST_CHECK.value))

def start_process():#Запуск Process
    p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=(LAST_CHECK,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    LAST_CHECK = manager.Value(c_char_p, "init")
    start_process()

    while True:
        a = input("input 1 for exit")
        if a == "1":
            break
        glob_check(LAST_CHECK)`
```

значение передается, но задача по расписанию отрабатывает 1 раз и вылетает ошибка

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anastasiia\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anastasiia\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anastasiia\pyproject\db_roszdrav\for_help.py", line 19, in start_schedule
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(P_schedule.check_news(LAST_CHECK))
  File "C:\Anastasiia\pyproject\venv\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 440, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Comment: multiprocessing процесс, создает собственную область видимости, не связанную с областью видимости главного процесса в котором выполняется glob_check(), т.е. LAST_CHECK в multiprocessing, и LAST_CHECK в  glob_check - это не одна и та же, а разные переменные

Comment: Как тогда мне передать данные из multiprocessing в главный процесс?

Comment: здесь вообще не нужен multiprocessing, это бессмысленно

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону потоков или асинхронных функций. Мультипроцессинг, фактически, это запуск двух разных интерпретаторов. При этом в менеджере задач можно увидеть два процесса `python.exe`

Comment: @vadim vaduxa, multiprocessing использую чтобы телеграмм бот выполнял некоторые задачи по расписанию, а в основном процессе можно было вести общение с ботом

Answer (score 0):

Итак, для для обмена значением LAST_CHECK между процессами задействован multiprocessing.Manager. А ошибка ***TypeError:the first argument must be callable.***  вылетала из-за того в `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(P_schedule.check_news(LAST_CHECK))` P_schedule.check_news нельзя вызывать, нужно передавать как функцию, т.о. задействована `partial(P_schedule.check_news, LAST_CHECK)`

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime
from ctypes import c_char_p
from multiprocessing.context import Process
from multiprocessing import Value, Manager
from functools import partial

class P_schedule:  # Class для работы с schedule
    @staticmethod
    def start_schedule(LAST_CHECK):  # Запуск schedule
        print("schedule start")
        ######Параметры для schedule######
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(partial(P_schedule.check_news, LAST_CHECK))  # без partial здесь вылетала ошибка
        ##################################
    while True:  # Запуск цикла
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

@staticmethod
def check_news(LAST_CHECK):
    print("previos LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK.value)
    time.sleep(2)
    LAST_CHECK.value = 'Последняя проверка по расписанию ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("check_news by schedule LAST_CHECK = " + LAST_CHECK.value)


def glob_check(LAST_CHECK):
    print("info LAST_CHECK = " + str(LAST_CHECK.value))

def start_process():#Запуск Process
    p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=(LAST_CHECK,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    LAST_CHECK = manager.Value(c_char_p, "init") # задействовали Manager из  multiprocessing
    start_process()

    while True:
        a = input("input 1 for exit")
        if a == "1":
            break
        glob_check(LAST_CHECK)
```

Вот теперь все работает!!!

Comment: Поясните текстом перед кодом и пометьте комментариями в коде, какие изменения вы сделали, чтобы всё заработало.